# Grouping MySQL query by SUM (threshold)

Tags: mysql

I'm setting up a MySQL query that sums values from a database and groups these by thresholds, so it only outputs the 'milestones' when certain values were reached.

The database looks like:

```
date       - number
2018-12-01 - 500
2018-12-02 - 400
2018-12-03 - 300
2018-12-04 - 500
2018-12-05 - 400
etc.
```

Expected output:

```
Milestone 500 = 2018-12-01
Milestone 1000 = 2018-12-03
Milestone 2000 = 2018-12-05
etc.
```

*The milestones should show what the first date was that a certain milestone was surpassed. So 2018-12-03 is the first date that 1000 was surpassed.*

The 'milestones' won't be the same distance from each other in every occasion. So ideally I'm looking for a query that could combine SUM with IF and GROUP possibly?

I have been Googling for hours, but at a loss how I can do this, other than looping through all the results separately and counting the total values + if statements, which is resource consuming. If at all possible, I'd like to keep it within the query.

Comment: Your example is incomplete. I cannot reproduce your results. Milestone 1000 is 2018-12-03? Why?

Comment: Sorry, about that, happy to clarify: the numbers add up. So 2018-12-03 would be the first date where the summed numbers surpass 1000.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(date DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,number INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2018-12-01',500),
('2018-12-02',400),
('2018-12-03',300),
('2018-12-04',500),
('2018-12-05',400);

SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN total >=  500 THEN date END) milestone_500 
     , MIN(CASE WHEN total >= 1000 THEN date END) milestone_1000 
     , MIN(CASE WHEN total >= 2000 THEN date END) milestone_2000 
  FROM
     (
       SELECT x.*,SUM(y.number) total FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.date <= x.date GROUP BY x.date
     ) a;

+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| milestone_500 | milestone_1000 | milestone_2000 |
+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| 2018-12-01    | 2018-12-03     | 2018-12-05     |
+---------------+----------------+----------------+
```